# Comparison not working properly

Tags: c#

I'm making a Sudoku game, and have a problem.

See [my .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1JpoN) and an image of the output :

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bgfi.png)   ([image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k35An.png))

So what I did was generated random number couples (between 1 and 9, like (1,2)) and saved them one by one in an array. 
After that I checked that the next numbers generated should not be generated the same so I did comparison like

```
int[] randomNumbersArray13 = new int[9];
int[] randomNumbersArray23 = new int[9];
randomNumbersArray13[0] = 122;
randomNumbersArray23[0] = 12212;
int va12, vb12;

for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
{
    Same Class = new Same();
    va12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
    vb12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        while (va12 == randomNumbersArray1[i] && vb12 == randomNumbersArray2[i])
        {
            va12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            vb12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        while (va12 == randomNumbersArray12[i] && vb12 == randomNumbersArray22[i])
        {
            va12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            vb12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbersArray13.Length; i++)
    {
        while (va12 == randomNumbersArray13[i] && vb12 == randomNumbersArray23[i])
        {
            va12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            vb12 = rnd.Next(0, 9);
        }
    }

    Class.rows = va12;
    Class.column = vb12;
    randomNumbersArray12[k] = va12;
    randomNumbersArray22[k] = vb12;
    randomNumbersArray[va12, vb12] = 3;
    myExpenseManager.AddExpense(Class);
}
```

Comment: Please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the post.  Make it easy for someone to help you instead of making them go somewhere else to look at a picture of the code.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You only need to include 1 C# tag...

Comment: Saying you are creating a generator for a Sudoku game would have been very helpful, I was only able to determine this through the name on your screenshot.

Comment: Sorry but where is Facebook?

Comment: Yeah I am new here I'll take care to ask properly next time

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you have two arrays with random numbers, what are requirements?

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/perry-mitchell/sudoku-generator-cs/blob/master/source/BoardGenerator.cs

Comment: I am trying to create random numbers that will fit the sudoku box with position generated by random numbers like (1,2) of the sudoku 2-d array but i dont want the numbers to be regenrated

Comment: Like randomarray1 and 2 are for the position variable(x,y) for number 1 and randomarray 12 & 13 are for the position variable(x,y) for number 2 .............

Comment: Consider shuffling a list of items that you want to use, and then pulling the items from that list sequentially. Choosing a random item over and over again until you have a unique one could potentially take forever.

Comment: Ohh yeah I think that could be helpful

Comment: Since this is Sudoku your board should be **one** array, not a set of arrays.  And get some better variable names--what they do, not what they are!  And your code is failing because when a number fails you reroll--but don't redo the test(s) that already passed.  This routine ensures the numbers meet test #3 but will produce plenty that fail #1 and #2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give us a link to the full source code there's no way to understand the problem.

But I was able to infer from the output and existing code what was intended. I edited the question, and [added a dotnet fiddle, here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1JpoN).

You are doing an "expense" function (a type of score) on randomly selected Sudoku.

You have several problems. To make a long story short here's the code you need. Then I'll explain what was wrong with your code.

```
// I'm using i and j, instead of k and i that you used
// I'm using 2 dimensional arrays - see my code. 
// I'm using clear names. 
// There's only one variable: 'v'.  v holds the current random value. 

for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
    for (var j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            // if non-unique in the row/column or non-unique in the square, then re-randomize
            // Also check that it's unique in your resulting array
            // you'll need a special function to check which square your in... 
            // not in the scope of my answer. If you want, ask and I'll show you how. 
            // meanwhile let's check that in this row and column of the unique array it's unique
            for (var m=0; m<i; m++)
               for (var n=0; n<j; n++)
                   while (v == uniqueArray[m,j] || v == uniqueArray[i,n] 
                      ||  v == rowcolArray[i,j] || v == squaresArray[i,j])
                v = rnd.Next(1,9);

            // and now use the unique number in your two dimensional array
            uniqueArray[i,j] = v;
            scoreArray[i,j] = 3; 
            // probably scoreArray should be with some kind of algorithm,
            // outside the scope of this answer. Ask if you still need to understand
            same = new Same(i,j);
            myExpenseManager.AddExpense(same);
          }
        }
```

Your problems:

1. Diagonals: You are iterating on the diagonals - so you never compare the full row or the full column. You are checking row 1 col 1, then row 2 col 2.
   The same is true when you check the squares. You check square 1 - place 1, then you check square 2 - place 2... instead of checking row 1 col 1,2,3... then row 2 col 1,2,3...  etc.  You forgot to use k!!
2. You are randomizing from 0 to 9 instead of from 1 to 9.
3. You are doing an && while you should be doing an || to check that you are unique. && will be true only BOTH PAIRs are the same: rn1Array[i] = va12 AND rn2Array[i] = vb12. For example, with i=9: If va=5 and rn1[9]=5 it still won't choose a new va UNLESS the vb and rn2[9] are equal. So, to continue this example, if vb=7 but rn2[9]=6 the current va will be accepted! And since you iterate on all arrays with the same variables (that are supposedly unique from the last 9 comparisons) it will re-randomize ONLY IF there are 3 times THREE VALUES that are the same:

   va12: say randomly chosen: 7
   rn21[i:9] say 7
   vb12: say randomly chosen: 5
   rn22[i:9]: say 5. THIS IS THE ONLY CASE THAT WE RE-RANDOMIZE
     But now that we re-randomized, va12: 3, vb12: 8 
     and we check rn31[i:9] and rn32[i:9]
     we'll re-randomize a second time only if rn31=3 AND rn32=8.
4. You stored the VALUE of the comparison in the row and column of Class. You should store the i and k  which are the row and column.
5. You are using variable and class names that are not clear.

   - Calling a variable Class - is not a good idea.
   - Calling the class Same - is not clear
   - Calling the arrays with long unclear names makes the code hard to understand
6. You are iterating on the whole array that you are now adding to. rnArr31 and rnArr32...
7. You entered numbers not from 1 to 9 in the rn31 and rn32 array.